# Does install4j support sending --webhook argument to the new notarytool?

Tags: macos, install4j, notarize

I have install4j setup to notarize one of my macos applications. I migrated from version 8.0 to 10.0.6
Before I migrated I uses to get an email from Apple with the results of the notarization. I know install4j v10.0.5+ uses the new notarytool, which as apple stated in their docs no longer sends out an email when notarization is completed. They recommend using the --webhook flag in the notarytool to get a callback once the notarization is completed. Is there any way to pass a webhook URL while using install4j to notarize the application?

So far I've read the install4jc documentation and there does not seem to be any mention of sending webhook flag to the notarytool.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform the notarization in install4j (as of 10.x this has to be done on macOS), then the build will be completed once the notarization is complete. install4j will also staple the notarization result to the DMG.

So there is nothing you have to do to wait for the notarization to complete.